DNS over TLS with Bind9 9.20, failure of one forwarder halts the whole server
Ubuntu 22.04 with Bind9 9.20.0.
I have the following config in named.conf.options file
tls Cloudflare-DoT {
        remote-hostname "one.one.one.one";
        protocols {
                TLSv1.3;
        };
        cipher-suites TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256;
};

tls Google-DoT {
        remote-hostname "dns.google";
        protocols {
                TLSv1.3;
        };
        cipher-suites TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256;
};
...
options {
        recursion yes;
        forward only;
        forwarders port 853 {
                1.1.1.1 tls "Cloudflare-DoT";
                1.0.0.1 tls "Cloudflare-DoT";
                2606:4700:4700::1111 tls "Cloudflare-DoT";
                2606:4700:4700::1001 tls "Cloudflare-DoT";
                8.8.8.8 tls "Google-DoT";
                8.8.4.4 tls "Google-DoT";
                2001:4860:4860::8888 tls "Google-DoT";
                2001:4860:4860::8844 tls "Google-DoT";
                8.8.4.4 tls "Google-DoT";
        };
};


It works exactly as expected, bind9 queries get forwarded to either cloudflare or google over TLS.
I decided to test how bind9 will behave if TLS fails on just one of the forwarders. To test it, I changed remote-hostname field in Google-DoT to dnsfail.google.
I was expecting to see something in the logs about Google-DoT forwarders being unavailable, but bind9 to continue to work using Cloudflare-DoT only. What is actually happening is that bind9 stops using all forwarders, including Cloudflare-DoT which has correct configuration. Furthermore, I do not see anything in the logs indicating that there is a problem (I'm checking journalctl -u named.
Why is bind9 behaving like this?
